# Retrieving Http Get url from a html form via jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Is there any way to retrieve a from url with out submitting it, some how simulating a form submission via HTTP Get.
I mean for this example

```
<from id="frm" method="POST" action='someaction'>
  <input type='text' id='txt1' value='Hello'/>
<form>
```

I want to get bellow string without submitting form

```
someaction?txt1=Hello
```

Comment: This is what AJAX is all about.

Comment: @Barmar I have an <a> link and I just want to concat this url to href attribute of link, so how AJAX can help me on this situation?

Comment: `$('#frm').attr('action') +  $('#frm').serialize()`, but you'll need valid HTML, which you don't have ?

Comment: @RezaRahmati So you don't want a form at all...you just want to grab the current addresses query string and append it to an anchor tag on the page?

Comment: @kevindeleon I need from because in my real case I have a submit button on the form and form can be submitted independently. also I have a link and I want to add url to link's href so that whenever use clicks on the link I will have form data on server via request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

HTML:

```
<form id="frm" method="POST" action='someaction'>
  <input type='text' id='txt1' value='Hello'/>
  <input type='text' id='txt2' value='World'/>
</form>

Your GET URL is: <div id="url"></div>
```

Javascript (using jQuery):

```
var url = $("#frm").attr("action") + "?";
var urlElements = [];
$("#frm").children().each(function(){
    urlElements.push($(this).attr("id") + "=" + $(this).attr("value"));
});
urlElements = urlElements.join("&");
url += urlElements;
$("#url").html(url);
```

You can test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/3S9db/

Hope this help :)

Comment: thanks but it doesn't work if there was other tags in the form such as div or fieldset 
`<form id="frm" method="POST" action='someaction'>
    <div id='div'>
  <input type='text' id='txt1' value='Hello'/>
  <input type='text' id='txt2' value='World'/>
    </div>
</form>`

Comment: Thanks, after changing .children to .find('input') I add an if to your code and it works fine.
`if ($(this).attr("id") != undefined && $(this).attr("type") != 'submit') {
    urlElements.push($(this).attr("id") + "=" + $(this).attr("value"));
}`

Comment: Also, usually form query string arguments names are in the `name` attribute, not the `id` attribute. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q63w6/) generalizes and fixes this and the other issues.

Answer (score 4):

Like @adeneo said:

```js
$('#frm').attr('action') + '?' + $('#frm').serialize()
```

Comment: You should really not post someone else's comment verbatim as your own answer. It's bad form at best, and at worst it could amount to plagiarism.

Comment: So, how to highlight his comment ? which seems to be the best answer ?

Comment: @JustinMorgan: meta says it's okay, if you mark as community wiki: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: @user - Noted. Removed my -1.

Comment: @JustinMorgan: smart idea to edit so you can remove the downvote

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about sending data to server, It's possible to do it via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). But there is no difference actually. You must send data through HTTP request some how. 
The only difference between sending via ajax form and the ordinary form is that in ajax the page will not be reloaded but in ordinary form submission the page will be reloaded.
 There are other ways like [Node.JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodejs%E2%80%8E) too.
 But all of them are doing the same thing. You don't have any choice to send data through HTTP.

**EDIT**

---

But if you want to do that on client side, you can do something like this: [**jsFiddle Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/t7e55/6/)

HTML:

```
<from id="frm" method="POST" action='someaction'>
  <input type='text' id='txt1' value='Hello'/>
  <input type='text' id='txt2' value='hi'/>
  <input type='text' id='txt3' value='hoy'/>
<form>

<a class='link' href="">This is link1<a><br>
```

JS:

```
var str = $('#frm').attr('action')+'?';
$('#frm input[type="text"]').each(function(i , o) {
   var val = $(this).val();
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(i==0){
         str += id+'='+val;
    }
    else{
        str += '&'+id+'='+val;
    }
});

$('a.link').attr('href', str);
```

Comment: You know I don't want to submit mu data to server, I just want to get the url and add url to an <a> href link.

Comment: This is what i want, but I needa general function, since my forms has different elements I can not hard code this part `'someaction?txt1='+val)`. is there any general solution?

Comment: it is still buggy when there is  `<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>` in the form, but it can be resolved by an if statement. ;)

Comment: @RezaRahmati Edited. general solution. Bug fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myaction = $("#frm").attr( "action" );
var txt1 = $( "#txt1" ).val();
var mystr = myaction  + "?txt1=" + txt1;
```

or

```
var mystr = $("#frm").attr( "action" ) + "?txt1=" + $( "#txt1" ).val();
```

then

```
$.ajax({
    url: mystr,
    method: "GET"
}).done( function( data ){
   //do whatever 

});
```

UPDATED:

There are ways of generalizing a solution. One would be to use an input button to call a function and pass it the form, then get the form data from the form id.

```
function submitMyForm(frmId){
    var  i, 
         val,
        elements = [],
        ele = $( ":input", "#" + frmId );
    // or
    var i, 
        val,
        elements = [],
        ele = $( "#" + frmId + " > *" );
    // returns an array of form elements for the form you specified
    $.each( ele, function( i, obj ){
      // skip the type = button, otherwise process form elements appropriately
      val = { name: $( obj ).attr('name'), value: $ (obj ).val() });
      elements.push(val);
      // elements should now hold your form values in key/value object pairs. 
    }
}


<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitMyForm( $( this ).parent().attr('id')">
```

This solution assumes you have an id value for each form. I have not checked the code for errors, but this should give you the idea of what you need to do. The $.each function needs work- you need to skip processing buttons, and if you have checkboxes, you might need extra code to detect whether they are checked, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is what i want but I want a general function, since my forms has different elements I can not hard code this part `"?txt1=" + $( "#txt1" ).val();` is there any general solution?